# problems with stripe and react state/global state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to set up stripe.js with my app. I have literally every single thing done and when the purchase is complete stripe passes the client to a success page. The problem I am having is that stripe seems to be resetting my application (the props + state from previously rendered components before stripe.js' checkout are not being passed through) in order to properly show the appropriate data on this success page i need the state from previous components.

I am using stripe's redirectToCheckout function and it redirects out of the app .maybe a serverless function from JAMstack could send the data between stripe? Someone please let me know! Here is some of my code below for the stripe part of my app. There isn't really a specific part of my code to show that would help answering this question tbh. It's a fundamental question of whether there is a way to not have stripe reset my app thus losing previous state after redirecttoCheckout function.

The response (or data on products and session etc) is coming from a serverless netlify function. which is why i mentioned it above. Maybe that could be a possible help

```
//client sides
import {loadStripe} from "@stripe/stripe-js"

export async function handleFormSubmission(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const form = new FormData(event.target);

  const data = {
    sku: form.get('sku'),
    quantity: Number(form.get('quantity')),
  };


  const response = await fetch('/.netlify/functions/create-checkout', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  }).then((res) => res.json())
  const stripe=await loadStripe(response.publishableKey);
  const {err}=await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    sessionId:response.sessionId
  })


  if(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
}
//client sides
import {loadStripe} from "@stripe/stripe-js"

export async function handleFormSubmission(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const form = new FormData(event.target);

  const data = {
    sku: form.get('sku'),
    quantity: Number(form.get('quantity')),
  };


  const response = await fetch('/.netlify/functions/create-checkout', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  }).then((res) => res.json())
  const stripe=await loadStripe(response.publishableKey);
  const {err}=await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    sessionId:response.sessionId
  })


  if(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please format the text description of your question, it is very difficult to read 20 lines of uncapitalized text with little punctuation and no paragraph breaks.

Comment: thanks for the help.

Comment: When you call `.redirectToCheckout` it (unsurprisingly) redirects you to Stripe's page, if you want the app state persisted then you'll have to tuck it somewhere (e.g. localStorage). None of your code after that call runs, because the page is gone.

Comment: thanks so much man. before even reading your comment i actually attempted to use local storage. so far so good! thanks for the help sry for being snippy before lol

Comment: hey man. local storage was working great until i tried to test the deployed version on netlify... im really so upset to see this. i tried everything..... how exactly does local storage work?

Comment: It's specific to the originating domain, your localStorage data from development won't be there when you test the prod version: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: it actually works fine in test mode now.... it was just my cookies and cache from old deployment (at least thats my assumption)... so what exactly do you mean by local data not available in development. each client's local storage will still be in their own personal local storage correct?

Comment: Yes, but localStorage is also *per originating domain* because of security reasons: one site's localStorage can't be read by another site not from the same domain. Unless your dev environment and prod environment are the same originating domain (unlikely) then whatever you put in there while running e.g. a local webserver won't be visible to your production site.